# Is it possible to prevent postback when changing the GridView Paging Index?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, postback

I am trying to create my own online quiz website using ASP C#.

I tried to bind the question from database into `gridview` and set the page size of the `gridview` to 1.
And then I tried to pull the answers option (4 option) into `radioButton`.

But when I tried to move from the 1 page of `gridview` to another page, the checked value lost. I know thats because of when we changed the `gridview` page, it will do a `postback`.

My Questions are:

1. Why I can't access my `RadioButton` from CodeBehind? Is it because of inside the Updatepanel ?
2. Is it possible if we want to do a page index change in gridview without `postback`? Or,
3. is there another option to make my `RadioButton` checked value not lost when changing to the next page (next question) ?

here are my code :

**`**`quiz.aspx :`**`**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="grdquestions" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false" OnPageIndexChanging="grdquestions_PageIndexChanging" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="QuestionId" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" AllowCustomPaging="False" PageSize="1" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOJO eQuiz">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table class="tableclass" id='<%#Eval("QuestionId") %>'>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Question : <%#Eval("Question") %></b>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnquestionId" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table>

                                        <tr style="margin-top: 10px;">

                                            <td>
                                                <table class="tblOptions">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdOption1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option1") %>' GroupName="chcbox" />

                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdOption2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%#Eval("Option2") %>' GroupName="chcbox" />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdOption3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text='<%#Eval("Option3") %>' GroupName="chcbox" />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rdOption4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Option4") %>' GroupName="chcbox" />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lbquestionstatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="GridPager" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**`**`quiz.aspx.cs`**`**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["username"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindGrid();

            }
            else
            {
            }
        } 
    }


 public void BindGrid()
    {
        var sess = Session["username"].ToString();
        string a = sess.Substring(sess.Length - 1);

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from dojoquiz order by " + a + "", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dashboardConnectionString"].ToString());
        adp.Fill(dt);

        grdquestions.DataSource = dt;
        grdquestions.DataBind();
    }

protected void grdquestions_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            RadioButtonList rdlstOptions = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("rdlstOptions");
            HiddenField hdnquestionId = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hdnquestionId");
            if (rdlstOptions != null && hdnquestionId != null)
            {
                DataRow[] result = dt.Select("questionid=" + (Convert.ToInt32(hdnquestionId.Value)));
                DataView view = new DataView();
                view.Table = dt;
                view.RowFilter = "questionid=" + (Convert.ToInt32(hdnquestionId.Value));
                if (view.Table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                    dt1 = view.ToTable();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void grdquestions_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grdquestions.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        this.BindGrid();
    }
```

Thank you for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried passing the checkbox value when changing index?

Comment: I can't access my RadioButton from code behind, edited my question. Why I can't get my RadioButton ID ? please help.

Comment: It is because you are calling BindGrid() again on PageIndexChanging event.

Comment: @Atk yes I know. But without calling BindGrid() again, the GridView value wouldn't change if I change the paging index.. Do you have any suggestion? Or any method if without using gridview?

Comment: @RANDY there are so many ways you can achieve this. Whenever checkbox is checked, store that result in a data table along with entire row. On pageindex change event bind your grid to that data table.

Answer (score 0):

If the sql query is not change, then don't do `DataBind()` on post back, but you still need to give him the data source to get the data. So your code must be as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGrid();
}

public void BindGrid()
{
    var sess = Session["username"].ToString();
    string a = sess.Substring(sess.Length - 1);

    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from dojoquiz order by " + a + "", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dashboardConnectionString"].ToString());
    adp.Fill(dt);

    grdquestions.DataSource = dt;

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        grdquestions.DataBind();
}
```

Its not possible with out post back to change page or do thinks on GridView, but if you make it correct this is not an issue.

Comment: But I need to bind into gridview when Page_Load for the first time..

Comment: @RANDY see this point `if (!Page.IsPostBack) grdquestions.DataBind();` This is make the DataBind ones when the page is first load.